# Poor write performance on Debian server running NFS with 22TB exported JFS filesystem

Tags: linux, debian, nfs, jfs

I am currently running a debian server that is exporting a large JFS filesystem (22TB) over NFS (nfs-kernel-server.)  When attempting to write to the NFS share, the performance is very poor.  The 22TB disk is sitting on a NAS mounted using iSCSI.

- It will bust for a moment near expected line speed, and then sit idle for several seconds.  Very little traffic measured in the low kb/sec.
- The wait peeks on write.
- When reading from the NFS mount, the system operates at expected speeds (11MB/sec).
- The issue does not occur when using SFTP, rsync, or local coping (non-nfs).
- The issue persists between stable and testing releases.
- On the same machine I have a 14TB ext4 filesystem using the exact same export configuration that does not share the issue. This share is not in regular use and thus not consuming resources.

**NFS Server:**

```
cat /etc/exports
/data2      10.1.20.86(rw,no_subtree_check,async,all_squash)

cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/scheduler
noop [deadline] cfq

cat /etc/default/nfs-kernel-server 
RPCNFSDCOUNT=8
RPCNFSDPRIORITY=0
RPCMOUNTDOPTS=--manage-gids
NEED_SVCGSSD=
RPCSVCGSSDOPTS=
```

**NFS Client:**

```
cat /etc/fstab
10.1.20.100:/data2  /root/incoming  nfs     rw,noatime,soft,intr,noacl 0 2

cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/scheduler
noop [deadline] cfq

cat /proc/mounts
10.1.20.100:/data2/ /root/incoming nfs4 rw,noatime,vers=4,rsize=262144,wsize=262144,namlen=255,soft,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.1.20.86,minorversion=0,addr=10.1.20.100 0 0
```

This problem has me pretty stumped.  Any help would be greatly welcomed.  Thanks.

Comment: Is the mount options of the 14T and 22T the same on the NFS server?

Comment: Other questions, NETWORK:
-> How many network interfaces does the server have? -> Bonded Interfaces?
-> Is the iSCSI and NFS traffic isolated from other network traffic? -> either with vlans or separate switches? -> network: is jumboframes enabled?
-> Does the iSCSI server accessed via a different vlan, ie network traffic flows through a router?
-> Client network configuration/speed? iSCSI -> raid configuration? Thats a couple of questions that will help with a answer :)

Comment: Yeah, I don't know that people use JFS in this setup often. If ext4 doesn't exhibit the issue, perhaps that's an indicator that the issues lies with the filesystem.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but some info and questions. You have 2 layers in here and 3 points of observation. Layers are: * JFS layer (The one talking to the disk) * I haven't noticed you're mentioning what is the exact mount options list you're using, to mount, maybe there is some place of improvement there. * NFS layer (the shared one): * NFS has statistics tool, `nfsstat` Observation points are: * local point, local fs * NFS server * NFS client What I'd suggest is running `nfsstat` on client and server, before, during and after the write/read test, AND on both - the **good** and the **bad** v

Comment: did you tryto use nfs v3? mount -o vers=3. V4 performace very havely depends on the kernel version.

Comment: Are you write heavy, ready heavy or a little bit of both? I noticed you are using deadline for your i/o scheduler. Did you get worse performance when you were using cfq?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the number of NFS server threads is too low. Instead of 8, the number should be much higher.

8 threads would probably be enough for shares that contain only small files and are accessed by a very small number of clients (e.g. in a home network) or on slow networks (10 Mbit).

Try to determine the retrans value on your NFS server during writing:

```
nfsstat -r
```

If you get transmission retries, increase the number of server threads.

And I think it would be save to remove the rsize / wsize / tcp settings from your mount options. TCP is the default protocol anyway and with TCP it is not necessary to limit the transfer size.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect some problem with JumboFrames. Check offloading configuration on both your interfaces using

```
sudo ethtool -k your_nic
```

and also try listening the wires using wireshark. You may find some out-of-order packets, dups, ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is incompatibility with nfs locking used for writting and jfs. I found some bug in ubuntu:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jfsutils/+bug/754495